# Trying to display location data from Firebase to MapKit

Tags: swift, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit

searched about this question a lot but couldn't find a simple answer.

I want to be able to read location data from a Firebase database and display them on the MapKit as annotation.

Can you help?

Right now I can display annotations that are hard-coded but can't figure out how to read the database and then create a loop that displays all annotations on the map.

This is the code for showing the annotations.
I want to fill title, latitude, longitude with the relevant data from Firebase.
The Firebase database is as follows: [Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkXyc.png)

**The application is already connected with the Firebase!

```
let points = [
        ["title": ,    "latitude": , "longitude": ],    
    ]
    for point in points {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = point["title"] as? String
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: point["longitude"] as! Double)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
```

After suggestion I edited the code and it is like this right now:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("x-database-alpha/name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let title = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Title"] as! String?
        let latitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Latitude"] as! String?
        let longitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Longitude"] as! String?

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Double(latitude!))!, longitude: (Double(longitude!))!)
        annotation.title = title
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    })
```

Check the[Exact Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIBRQ.png)

Right now the code has no error but it doesn't present the annotation!

Comment: Post what you have done, to help you.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa thanks! I posted the code below. Let me know what else is necessary.

Comment: Please [edit] the code in your question instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

let title = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Title"] as! String!
let latitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Latitude"] as! String!
let longitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Longitude"] as! String!

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Double(latitude!))!, longitude: (Double(longitude!))!)
annotation.title = title
self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It gives me this error on:  let title = ... --> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Fixed the error by correcting the "name." However the annotation from the database doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited the original post -- please check!